# How do I set up a nested field in a Cloud Firestore database using JSONserializable in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, json-serializable

I have set up two of the Collections in My Cloud Firestore database in Flutter using JSONSerializable. This is shown below

**models.dart**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
part 'models.g.dart';

enum RecordType {
  weightAndReps,
  repsOnly,
  time,
  timeAndWeight,
  distance,
}

@JsonSerializable()
class User {
  final String id;
  final String username;
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String password;
  final String image;
  final bool isAdmin;

  User(
      {this.id = '',
      this.username = '',
      this.name = '',
      this.email = '',
      this.password = '',
      this.image = '',
      this.isAdmin = false});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Exercise {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String description;
  final String image;
  final RecordType recordType;
  final String primaryMuscleGroup;
  final List<String> secondaryMuscleGroup;

  Exercise(
      {this.id = '',
      this.name = '',
      this.description = '',
      this.image = '',
      this.recordType = RecordType.weightAndReps,
      this.primaryMuscleGroup = '',
      this.secondaryMuscleGroup = const []});

  factory Exercise.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ExerciseFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ExerciseToJson(this);
}
```

However, I am having problems with the Workout Collection due to the number of nested fields and the fact that the Map datatypes in use have more than two elements which I cannot utilise in dart. I am fairly new to this and cannot find much online on how to do this. The collection in question is shown in the image below.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your workout collection can be represented by the below model.

```
class Workout {
  final int durationInWeeks;
  final String image;
  final String name;
  final List<Session> sessions; // Session defined below

  Workout({
    required this.durationInWeeks,
    required this.image,
    required this.name,
    required this.sessions,
  });

  factory Workout.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$WorkoutFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$WorkoutToJson(this);
}

class Session {
  final String description;
  final List<Exercise> exercise;
  final int weeklySessions;

  Session({
    required this.description,
    required this.exercise,
    required this.weeklySessions,
  });

  factory Session.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$SessionFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$SessionToJson(this);
}
```